# GoDaddy htaccess redirect site root to public folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

here is my site map:

```
/www.myMainSite.com
|   .htaccess 
|   index.php
|   
+---/www.myShaerHostedSite1.com
| 
+---/www.myShaerHostedSite2.com
| 
+---/www.myShaerHostedSite3.com
      |     .htaccess 
      |     index.php
      |   
      +---includes
      |       config.php
      |       functions.php
      |  
      \---public
      |    .htaccess
      |    index.php
      | 
      +---errors
      |       404.php 
      | 
      |+---forms
      |       forms.php 
      |    
      |+---admin
        index.php
```

Here are my goals:

1. redirect `www.myShaerHostedSite3.com` to a sub folder `www.myShaerHostedSite3.com/public` (deny access to the root)
2. remove the `public` from the URL
3. deny access to the `includes` folder
4. password protect the `admin` folder (this is where I add/delete users)
5. define a custom error 404 page

I also want all pages and subfolders to look like they reside on the site root:

`www.myShaerHostedSite3.com/public/about.php` ==> `www.myShaerHostedSite3.com/about.php`

`www.myShaerHostedSite3.com/public/forms/forms.php` ==> `www.myShaerHostedSite3.com/forms/forms.php`

I am on a GoDaddy shared hosting. I know (now) that a lot of web developers don't like them, but this is where I am at now.

I have been reading posts about this and trying everything, nothing works. Even apache.org was no help.

This is my .htaccess file in the root:

```
    #GoDaddy needs this to run 
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
    ServerSignature off
    ErrorDocument 404 /public/404.php
    <Files .htaccess>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files config.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    </Files>
    ### GoDaddy needs these settings
    Options -Indexes -Multiviews +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myShaerHostedSite3\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.myShaerHostedSite3\.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1
```

I did not even get to the password protection yet because I can't even get the Rewrite to work.

I even tried the URL Redirects in the hostingmanager panel (as GoDaddy support recommended).

I keep getting errors (page not available or something). My error pages do not even work.

This is making me nuts. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The error I get is **500 - Internal Server Error**

Comment: Can you check your Apache error.log and see what the error is.

Comment: @anubhava this is from the Apache error log: `[core:error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9354] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: You have provided root .htaccess but as per image you have one inside `/public/` also. Can you provide that .htaccess also?

Comment: @anubhava I do not have an .htaccess file for public. It was my understanding that .htaccess behaved like .css; the rules set at the top filter down. Do I need a .htaccess file in /public? If so, what should it do?

Comment: But in your question you have shown `.htaccess` twice, didn't you?